# Why aren't some codeblocks highlighted?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

More often, I see some codeblocks [like this c block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45340/72471) or [this bash block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/72471), which just aren't highlighted.

Often simple constructs like for-loops etc [are, indeed, highlighted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26066/72471). But it looks broken.

And sometimes, [it works better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89587/72471). This example only highlights the alias string, but not the alias command itself. It highlights the `function()`, though.

Another answer in the same thread, however, highlights `eval`, so why is `alias` not highlighted?

- Why is that?
- Is that a bug?
- Is it broken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code highlighter is more often than not tied to the tags on the questions - tags can have a highlighting hint tied to them, but the c tag didn't have one.

I've set that up, so the c block actually highlights now.

Sometimes, the highlighter doesn't figure out what it needs to do, so needs help in the form of a highlighting hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
```

This is described in the editing help section about [syntax highlighting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).